# Google Apps Script Function output can not be stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, flatten

I have an array that I want to flatten in order to iterate over it. I get the array and then flatten it with the following function:

```
var Array = ss.getRange("G2:G").getValues(); ArrayFlat = flatten(Array);
```

Flatten helperfunction

```
function flatten(array) {
  var flattenedArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    flattenedArray.push(array[i][0])
  }
  return flattenedArray;
}
```

I would expect the same output for the last two following logs, but I get different logs.

```
function test() {
  Logger.log(Array) // unflattened array
  Logger.log(flatten(Array)) // flattended array
  Logger.log(ArrayFlat) // []
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, i.e. where the error lies?

EDIT: I have a solution to my problem (flat()), but not an answer to my question as to why my logs output is so different?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`ss.getRange("G2:G").getValues().flat();`

[Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
function flatten() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const array = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var fA = [];
  if(array.length) {
    array.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(array[i].length) {
        r.forEach((c,j) => {
          fA.push(c);
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    fA.push(r[0])
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(fA));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the .flat() solution works like a charm. Do you have an explanation to why it does not work with my helperfunction?

Comment: Well for one thing there's only one loop and your array is a two dimensional object so your not reach all of the elements

Comment: May array is = [[abc],[def],[ghi]] and my flattened array is [abc,def,ghi]. My loop is going through all aelements and pushes them into the new array hence: array[i][0]. I am not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: array[i][0] is the first column in every row.   If you wish to flatten the entire array it should look like [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i].  You can single step with the debugger and figure this out.